# SAP HANA XS Engine Odata Service doesn't let me Create/Update/Delete

Tags: odata, hana, hana-xs

I hava a SAP HANA XS Server with some DB Tables and an OData service. I am able to connect to the OData service and to read data. As soon as I try to Create/Update/Delete data I get the `403 - Forbidden` Error.
Actually my user has the required rights to execute all of the mentioned actions (I created data using the SQL command line in HANA Studio). When I try the same with the SYSTEM user I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

If your .xsaccess file looks like this:

```
{
    "prevent_xsrf": true,
    ...
}
```

you have to fetch an XSRF-token before you modify your entity. Reading the entity works without.

Such a token can be obtained by executing a GET to the service endpoint with following header `X-CSRF-Token=Fetch`. The response contains a header like this `X-CSRF-Token=13DC4988AEAA95...`. If you execute your e.g. POST now with the just obtained token it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your OData service is defined to not allow modifications of the data.

From the [SAP HANA Developer Guide](http://help.sap.com/hana/SAP_HANA_Developer_Guide_for_SAP_HANA_Studio_en.pdf):

> By default, all entity sets and associations in an OData service are writeable, that is they can be modified with a CREATE, UPDATE, or DELETE requests. However, you can prevent the execution of a modification request by setting the appropriate keyword (*create*, *update*, or *delete*) with the `forbidden` option in the OData service definition. The following example of an OData service definition for SAP HANA XS shows how to prevent any modification to the table `myTable` that is exposed by the OData service. Any attempt to make a modification to the indicated table using a CREATE, UPDATE, or DELETE request results in the HTTP response status `403 FORBIDDEN`.

```
service {
  “sap.test::myTable”
    create forbidden
    update forbidden
    delete forbidden;
}
```